# SIMBL installation error? No folder Library/Applications Support/SIMBL

Tags: macos, simbl

Terminal returned "installation successful" but when searching for the folder `Library/Applications Support/SIMBL` it does not exist.

Does it mean it wasn't installed? Will I have to uninstall it or can I try to install it again as it is.

No errors were ever returned.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you were looking in the user library instead of the global library folder.

`~/Library` vs `/Library`

You should uninstall SIMBL and install [mySIMBL](https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL)*.

The original SIMBL has not been functional since Apple implemented System Integrity Protection.

* I am the developer of mySIMBL

Comment: No it was in the right place since the folder `Library/Applications Support/` existed, just not the SIMBL folder. Thanks! I will see how I do with mySIMBL